# onClientClick executes and then the page postbacks immediately

Tags: jquery, asp.net, frontend

I have the following code:

functions.js =>

```
function loadPopup() {
    $("#backgroundPopup").css({
        "opacity": "0.7"
    });
    $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#popupContact").fadeIn("slow");
}

//disabling popup with jQuery magic!  
function disablePopup() {
    $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#popupContact").fadeOut("slow");
}

//centering popup  
function centerPopup() {
    //request data for centering  
    var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var popupHeight = $("#popupContact").height();
    var popupWidth = $("#popupContact").width();
    //centering  
    $("#popupContact").css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": windowHeight / 2 - popupHeight / 2,
        "left": windowWidth / 2 - popupWidth / 2
    });
    //only need force for IE6  

    $("#backgroundPopup").css({
        "height": windowHeight
    });

}

function no() {
    return false;
    disablePopup();
}

function yea() {
    $('#form1').submit(function () {
        return true;
    })
}

$(function () {
    $("#popupContactClose").bind('click', function () {
        disablePopup();
    });
});

function yeah() {
    $(this).bind('click', function (event) {

        centerPopup();

        loadPopup();

    });
}
```

---

... and the following markup:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" OnClientClick="yeah();" Text="Click me!" />
    <div id="popupContact">
        <a onclick="xClick()" id="popupContactClose">x</a>
        <input type="submit" onclick="yea()" value="Yes" />
        <input type="button" onclick="no()" value="No" />
    </div>
    <div id="backgroundPopup">
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

problem is that the OnClientClick event calls yea(), the div shows up and then disappears immediately and the page posts back. This is rather strange. Can you help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to snuff out the event.

```
onclick="yea();return false;"
```

Will probably do it.

Comment: Though given what you added to the previous person who tried to answer this might not do what you want either. In which case you probably need to submit the form via javascript in yea().

Comment: I guess you're right. the solution you gave here is not valid. It does trigger a post however, my server-side code doesn't execute.. :/ Any suggestions? Btw, thanks for taking the time to answer my question Mark

Comment: I thought that the common practice is function yea(e){/*user code*/e.preventDefault();} onclick="yea(event);"

Comment: Pencho, so what do you suggest? I'm not that familiar with javascript and jquery. I'm trying to pick it up quickly but i've bumped into a stonewall here.. Help wud be appreciated